# compiling Java error, cannot get constructor working

Tags: java, class, constructor

I am trying to code a simple bit of java but i cannot get it to compile
I have defined the objects within my class as so

```
    public class teams
    {
      public char sponsor;
      public char tires;
```

I am trying to set the default value of class sponsor to N/A

```
      public teams()
      {
      this.sponsor = "N/A";
      }
```

Can anyone figure out why it wont work? Im fairly new to java and i know this is probably extremely simple, any help would be appreciated!

EDIT
So thanks to Kevin Esche, I managed to get it to compile by using,
this.sponsor = 'N';

How would I get the term N/A instead of just N? Would I use unicode?, and if yes how do you format it?

Comment: you are trying to assign a `String` to a `char` which doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you make your sponsor a String

```
 public String sponsor;
```

Or you store only one character in it:

```
    sponsor = 'X';
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you Jan, that solved it. Couldn't see it staring me in the face as usual!